# Custom user.config save locations and naming

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the default user.config settings file, but I want to save it somewhere other than the default location. When trying to read and write to the file it doesn't do anything, but no errors are thrown. I also had to manually create the folder and file. Could someone show me where I am wrong here?

```
       location = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\MyProgram\" + Environment.UserName + ".config";
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("USER_CONFIG_FILE", location);
        textBox1.Text = Settings.Default["Text1"].ToString();
        label1.Text = Settings.Default["Text1"].ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.Default["Text1"] = textBox1.Text;
        Settings.Default.Save();
        label1.Text = Settings.Default["Text1"].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` to aaccess appdata folder and create  a folder named on the app and save the config globally or user specific.

### Code:

```
 var location = string.Format
(
@"{0}\MyApp\{1}",
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
Environment.UserName
);
// Create a confile using File IO Path
   var fileName = Path.Combine(location, "Data.Config")
```

### Why your code not working ?

You are trying to read settings from some location where your settings files is not available , where as you are writing the settings files in such a manner that app is assuming its in the bin directory, so these leads to nothing in your code.

Comment: See the attached code. If it fails, there are tons of aarticle for reading writing text files. You can create  a custom settings format for your app and save it where ever you want. But kindly note restricted areas in Win Vista and above wont allow you to read/write files. It will require elevated permisiion